# SQLite DB on android recreating records instead of calling onUpgrade()

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I've got some code that when I run it will add three records to the my SQLite DB which is created using my MySQLiteHelper class. The problem is that every time I run my application the three sample records are written into the DB again and don't replace their identical counterparts. So if I run my application 10 times there will be 30 records in my database.

**MapActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

    //ADD MAP MARKERS INTO DATABASE (PHASE TWO = FROM CSV FILE)
    db.addMapMarker(new MapMarker("Accommodation", 
                                  "Cardigan Costal Cottages", 
                                  "http://www.cardigan.cc/images/farmhouse/farmhouse.jpg", 
                                  "Four star accommodation!", 
                                  "Ffrwdwenith Isaf, Felinwyny, Cardigan, SA43 1RW",   
                                  "01974 272559", 
                                  "http://www.cardigan.cc", 
                                  52.2437596, -4.0930263));

    db.addMapMarker(new MapMarker("Activity",
                                  "Fforest",
                                  "http://www.coldatnight.co.uk/images/fforestcampcomforts.jpg", 
                                  "Offers a full range of half and full day activity packages.",
                                  "1 Cambrian Quay, Cardigan, SA43 2EZ",
                                  "01239 623633",
                                  "http://www.coldatnight.co.uk",
                                  52.1348785, -4.5411973));

   db.addMapMarker(new MapMarker("Food & drink",
                                  "Naturally Scrumptious",
                                  "http://www.naturallyscrumptious.co.uk/wp/images/3290f700c749.jpg",
                                  "Delicatessen and cafe bar",
                                  "18 Market Street, Aberaeron, SA46 0AS",
                                  "01545 574733",
                                  "http://www.naturallyscrumptious.co.uk",
                                  52.2424517, -4.2599518));
```

**SQLiteHelper.java**

```
package uk.ac.aber.dwd.util.CeredigionTourism;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    //Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CatalogueDB";

    //Catalogue records table name
    private static final String TABLE_RECORDS = "records";

    //Catalogue records column names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_GROUP = "category";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    private static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
    private static final String KEY_ADDR = "address";
    private static final String KEY_TELEPHONE = "telephone";
    private static final String KEY_URL = "url";
    private static final String KEY_LAT = "latitude";
    private static final String KEY_LNG = "longitude";

    //Array of Strings used to create database columns
    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID, KEY_GROUP, KEY_NAME, KEY_IMAGE, KEY_DESC, KEY_ADDR, 
                                             KEY_TELEPHONE, KEY_URL, KEY_LAT, KEY_LNG};

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //SQL statement to create records (map markers) table
        String CREATE_RECORDS_TABLE ="CREATE TABLE records (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
        "category TEXT, " + 
        "name TEXT, " +
        "image TEXT, " +
        "description TEXT, " +
        "address TEXT, " +
        "telephone TEXT, " +
        "url TEXT, " +
        "latitude TEXT, " +
        "longitude TEXT" + ")";

        //Create records (map markers) table
        db.execSQL(CREATE_RECORDS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //Drop older records table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS records");

        //create fresh records table
        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addMapMarker(MapMarker marker){

        //1. Get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //2. Create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_GROUP, marker.getGroup());
        values.put(KEY_NAME, marker.getName());
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, marker.getImage());
        values.put(KEY_DESC, marker.getDescription());
        values.put(KEY_ADDR, marker.getAddress());
        values.put(KEY_TELEPHONE, marker.getTelephone());
        values.put(KEY_URL, marker.getUrl());
        values.put(KEY_LAT, marker.getLatitude());
        values.put(KEY_LNG, marker.getLongitude());

        //3. Insert
        db.insert(TABLE_RECORDS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public MapMarker getMapMarker(int id){
        //1. Get reference to readable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        //2. Build query
        Cursor cursor =
                db.query(TABLE_RECORDS,
                        COLUMNS,
                        " id = ?",
                        new String[] {String.valueOf(id)},
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

        //3. If we got result get the first one
        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        //4. Build record object, each column iterates the index value. id = 0, group = 1, etc...
        MapMarker marker = new MapMarker();
        marker.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        marker.setGroup(cursor.getString(1));
        marker.setName(cursor.getString(2));
        marker.setImage(cursor.getString(3));
        marker.setDescription(cursor.getString(4));
        marker.setAddress(cursor.getString(5));
        marker.setTelephone(cursor.getString(6));
        marker.setUrl(cursor.getString(7));
        marker.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(8));
        marker.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(9));

        //5. Return marker
        return marker;
    }

    public List<MapMarker> getAllMapMarkers() {
        List<MapMarker> markers = new ArrayList<MapMarker>();

        //1. Build the query
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RECORDS;

        //2. Get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        //3. Go over each row, build marker and add it to list
        MapMarker marker = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                marker = new MapMarker();
                marker.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                marker.setGroup(cursor.getString(1));
                marker.setName(cursor.getString(2));
                marker.setImage(cursor.getString(3));
                marker.setDescription(cursor.getString(4));
                marker.setAddress(cursor.getString(5));
                marker.setTelephone(cursor.getString(6));
                marker.setUrl(cursor.getString(7));
                marker.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(8));
                marker.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(9));

                //Add marker to markers
                markers.add(marker);

            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        //Return markers
        return markers;
    }

    public int updateMapMarker(MapMarker marker) {
        //1. Get Reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //2. Create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_GROUP, marker.getGroup());
        values.put(KEY_NAME, marker.getName());
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, marker.getImage());
        values.put(KEY_DESC, marker.getDescription());
        values.put(KEY_ADDR, marker.getAddress());
        values.put(KEY_TELEPHONE, marker.getTelephone());
        values.put(KEY_URL, marker.getUrl());
        values.put(KEY_LAT, marker.getLatitude());
        values.put(KEY_LNG, marker.getLongitude());

        //3. Updating row
        int i = db.update(TABLE_RECORDS, values, KEY_ID + " ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(marker.getId()) });

        //4. Close
        db.close();

        return i;
    }

    public void deleteMapMarker(MapMarker marker) {
        //1. Get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //2. Delete
        db.delete(TABLE_RECORDS, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(marker.getId()) });

        //3. Close
        db.close();


    }
}
```

So I've written correct (I think!) code for the SQLiteHelper but every time my applications the records are duplicated instead of replaced. Perhaps there is a particular method I'm not calling?

Comment: I would put the 3 sample records creation in the DB's onCreate, instead of inside the Activity's onCreate. So, they would be added only after the table creation (which is also called by onUpgrade).

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the records already exist in the database and call updateMapMarker instead.

Are you sure you want to be creating/updating records each time your activity is created? Is sounds strange to me...

Comment: I think I'll try out Artoo Detoo's suggestion and create the records in the onCreate method of the database.

Comment: Sure, thats a good idea. If you want to be able to reset the markers back to default values just put everithing in a method and call it whenever necessary.